# Defining named set of dependencies in parent pom

Tags: maven

I would like to be able to define set of dependencies in parent pom and to be able to include these sets in children poms.

For instance:

```
parent pom {
   set1 {artifact1, artifact2, artifact3}
   set2 {artifact4, artifact5}
   set3 {artifact6, artifact7}
}

child1 pom {
   dependencies {set1, set2}
}

child2 pom {
   dependencies {set2, set3}
}
```

This behaviour is also described here (not implemented): http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Profiles+for+optional+dependencies

Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to achieve what you want via parent/child relationship of POMs (although would be glad to be corrected on this), but one solution that might work for you is to define groups of dependencies in their own POM file and then add a dependency to this POM in your individual modules.

So for example, here is a POM definition for some Spring dependencies:

```xml
<groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-deps</artifactId>
<version>SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>  
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Then in your module's pom you define a dependency to this pom:

```xml
<groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
<artifactId>module1</artifactId>
<version>SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-deps</artifactId>
        <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and all the Spring dependencies defined in the spring-deps pom are automatically included for you.

Comment: This is nice, if there is no better answer, I will accept it.

Comment: One more question - do I have to always install these `dependencies poms` or can I somehow link them to this child pom?

Comment: Glad you liked the answer. You'll always need to `mvn install` the dependencies poms.

Comment: The best thing is to use dependencyManagement in the parent pom and use the dependencies in the modules where they are needed. Otherwise it's sometimes hard to do analyzing etc.

Comment: @khmarbaise, very true and that is exactly how we do it in most of our projects. That said grouping dependencies is detailed by sonatype in their maven book under the chapter "POM Best Practices": http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html, so it is certainly a valid option for some projects. All depends on your needs I guess.